# how to remove mouse event from underwater bubble effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

i'm trying to make bubble effect inside a div. i've found a solution but it makes it with mouse events. but i want it to do that just inside a div. not with mouse. that div will gonna place horizontally middle of the browser. and shows bubbles after onclick event and stops in 10 seconds. see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBDy1.jpg

and you can also see the working demo on fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hfbcznfh/

can you please help me about that? i'm stucked.

here is my js code:

```
var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');

w = window.innerWidth;
h = window.innerHeight;

canvas.width = w;
canvas.height = h;

var mousex = -10000;
var mousey = -10000;

cntr = 0;

currentColor = Math.random();

var CircleArr = new Array();

var reset = function () {
    CircleArr = new Array();
    CircleArr[0] = {
        x: w / 2,
        y: h,
        s: h/50,
        color: hslToRgb(currentColor,1,.5)
    };
}

var update = function (modifier) {
    // MOVEMENT CODE
    var movConst = 100;

    if(cntr++ % 1 == 0){
        createCircle();
    }

    for(var circle in CircleArr){
        circle = CircleArr[circle];
        circle.x += Math.random()*10-5;
        circle.y -= Math.random()*10;
    }

    while(CircleArr.length > 2 && (CircleArr[0].x + CircleArr[0].s > w || CircleArr[0].x + CircleArr[0].s < 0 || CircleArr[0].y + CircleArr[0].s > h || CircleArr[0].y + CircleArr[0].s < 0) ){
        CircleArr.shift();

    }
};

function createCircle(){
    currentColor += Math.random();

    tmp = CircleArr[CircleArr.length-1];

    CircleArr[CircleArr.length] = {
        x: mousex,
        y: mousey,
        s: Math.random()*h/50,
        color: hslToRgb(currentColor % 1.00,1,.5)
    };
}

var render = function () {
    // wipe the canvas
    ctx.fillStyle = "#4BF";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,10000,100000);

    // draw the data
    for(var circle in CircleArr){
        current = CircleArr[circle];
        drawCircle(ctx,current.color,current.x,current.y,current.s,0,"#FFF");
    }

};

function drawCircle(ctx, fillColor, x, y, radius, strokeWidth, strokeColor){
    /*ctx.fillStyle = colorToHex("rgb("+fillColor[0].toFixed(0)+","+fillColor[1].toFixed(0)+","+fillColor[2].toFixed(0)+")");*/
    ctx.fillStyle = colorToHex("#EEE");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x,y,radius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
    ctx.closePath();
    if(strokeWidth != 0){
        ctx.lineWidth = strokeWidth;
        ctx.strokeStyle=strokeColor;
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    ctx.fill();
}

var main = function () {
    var now = Date.now();
    var delta = now - then;

    update(delta / 1000);
    render();

    then = now;
};

reset();
var then = Date.now();
setInterval(main, 1);

// onresize
$(window).resize(function() {
    w = document.body.clientWidth;
    h = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.height = h;
    canvas.width = w;
});

function hslToRgb(h, s, l){
    var r, g, b;

    if(s == 0){
        r = g = b = l; // achromatic
    }else{
        function hue2rgb(p, q, t){
            if(t < 0) t += 1;
            if(t > 1) t -= 1;
            if(t < 1/6) return p + (q - p) * 6 * t;
            if(t < 1/2) return q;
            if(t < 2/3) return p + (q - p) * (2/3 - t) * 6;
            return p;
        }

        var q = l < 0.5 ? l * (1 + s) : l + s - l * s;
        var p = 2 * l - q;
        r = hue2rgb(p, q, h + 1/3);
        g = hue2rgb(p, q, h);
        b = hue2rgb(p, q, h - 1/3);
    }

    return [r * 255, g * 255, b * 255];
}

function colorToHex(color) {
    if (color.substr(0, 1) === '#') {
        return color;
    }
    var digits = /(.*?)rgb\((\d+),(\d+),(\d+)\)/.exec(color);

    var red = parseInt(digits[2]);
    var green = parseInt(digits[3]);
    var blue = parseInt(digits[4]);

    var rgb = blue | (green << 8) | (red << 16);
    return digits[1] + '#' + rgb.toString(16);
};

document.onmousemove=getMouseCoordinates;
document.onclick=reset;
function getMouseCoordinates(event){
    ev = event || window.event;
    mousex = ev.pageX;
    mousey = ev.pageY;
    createCircle();
}
```

i really appreciate your helps.

best regards,
arja.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hfbcznfh/3/).  Let me know if that's what you had in mind!

**Explanation**:

We had to add a click listener to the container, to trigger the Bubbles.

```
var $bubbles = $('.bubbles');

$bubbles.click(function(){
    var interval = setInterval(main, 1);
    setTimeout(function(){
        clearInterval(interval);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#4BF";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,10000,100000);
    }, 10000);  // Animation time = 10,000ms / 10s
});
```

Also, I've reworked the `CircleArr` options, within `update`, to use the canvas position, instead of the mouse.

```
CircleArr[CircleArr.length] = {
    x: canvas.width/2,  // use canvas width to set x pos
    y: canvas.height/2, // use canvas height to set y pos
    s: Math.random()*h/50,
    color: hslToRgb(currentColor % 1.00,1,.5)
};
```

I've added just a bit of CSS, to get that div in the middle of the page:

```
.bubbles-outer
{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
canvas.bubbles
{
    background-color: #4BF;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: hello mac, many thanks for your helps. but this works messy. not like http://imgur.com/SKGfVE3  i think it can be done with x: canvas.width*Math.random() .. lines. isn't it? can you help me to do that? many thanks for your time again!

Comment: haybeye, yes! its a simple fix.  instead of canvas.width*Math.random(), you can use canvas.width/2.  I've updated the Fiddle and the code above! http://jsfiddle.net/hfbcznfh/3/ Let me know if that's what you had in mind.

Comment: one last thing how to make that div transparent? :) not with #4BF

Comment: and where to change animation time? it takes 10 seconds i guess

Comment: Do you want the canvas background to always be transparent? Or just before you click it?  If always, we'll have to make the bubbles a different color.  You can change the animation time by changing the setTimeout amount in the click listener.  I have highlighted it in the code above.

Comment: here is an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hfbcznfh/4/ with a transparent background

Comment: nope it shows grey background :( here is the page that i'm trying to do: http://goo.gl/fqPgDL you see i want that bubbling effect bottom of the page (not the middle) and want it transparent. that is all :/

Comment: Ok, you will have to position the canvas within the context of your webpage and not in the isolated Fiddle.  This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hfbcznfh/5/ has a transparent background and gray bubbles.